# Signed or Unsigned long for 8x8 game board in c

Tags: c, types, artificial-intelligence

I am programming a Reversi game in C, and i am new to the language (coming from java),and also have never programmed a game with 8x8 board before.   I want to use bit Boards to represent the game board for both white and black players (one 64 bit word for each), and i wonder if i should use an Unsigned long long for that purpose.

From what I know, an Unsigned Type is a one that doesn't use the leftMost bit as a sign indicator (0 for positive and 1 for negative), I also know that java for example,support only signed Types.      but in my case, I would need to use the left most bit as a valid square for the board.        Does it matter if i use a signed type or unsigned type for that??

for example, if i place a white piece on the last square of the white  bitBoard (the left most bit) and the number will become negative, is it ok?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you're doing things with bits, you'd better use unsigned.

Note that `unsigned long long` is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits, by the C standard.

Have a look at bit-fields, very handy in your case; saves you bit-fiddling with `&`, `|`, `^`, ...

But here's an idea:

```
#include <stdint.h>  // Thanks @DoxyLover
typedef struct
{
    uint8_t a : 1;
    uint8_t b : 1;
    uint8_t c : 1;
    uint8_t d : 1;
    uint8_t e : 1;
    uint8_t f : 1;
    uint8_t g : 1;
    uint8_t h : 1;
} BoardRow;

typedef struct
{
    BoardRow r1;
    BoardRow r2;
    BoardRow r3;
    BoardRow r4;
    BoardRow r5;
    BoardRow r6;
    BoardRow r7;
    BoardRow r8;
} Board;

void someFunction(void)
{
    Board board;

    board.r5.d = 1;
    ...

    // You can save these board in uint64_t if you like.
    uint64_t savedBoard = (uint64_t)board;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Use `#include <stdint.h>` and type `uint64_t` to guarantee 64 bit width.

Comment: I wonder what they do in Java when want to program a 8x8 board game and use 64 bit types?

Comment: "Need to" -- I don't think so. The sign will never change "on its own", and as long as the number is never treated as a *number* (i.e., doing calculations on it; printing it) but merely as a set of bits, then noone would notice it's "really" signed or unsigned, and negative or positive.

Comment: @user2030118: Use arrays?

Comment: @jongware That also crossed my mind but i just wansn't sure.  maybe there are things i don't know.  (I am also not an expert in bit manipulation,only did couple of simple games before)

Comment: @user2030118: I would use bits only if memory is tight or no bandwidth is available.

Comment: array would be the simplest solution, but with bit Boards i can do neat tricks with a great speed!   will save me a lot of long itterations over the array.

Comment: @user2030118 I hope you like the bit-board I suggest using bit fields.

Comment: @user2030118: speed depends on what you do with these bits. If all you do is testing and changing *individual* bits, then I suppose an array is faster, as it needs a lot of bit shifting. On the other hand, I used a simple bit list like this for a Sudoku solver, and then you can use ANDs and XORs to quickly get useful results. The same with an array of 0s and 1s would need loops.

Comment: `unsigned long long` **is** guaranteed to be at least 64 bit wide, by the standard